# Are These Leaf Fossils Found Near a Texas Lake Shore?

Tags: geology, rocks, fossils, paleobotany

I recently came across some intriguing specimens near a lake shore in Texas and am seeking your expertise to help identify them. The objects have a few characteristics that lead me to believe they could be fossils, but I would appreciate a more knowledgeable perspective.

Description:

**Size**: Each specimen is approximately 1-2 cm tall and has a thickness of about 1-2 mm.
**Shape**: They have a leaf-like appearance.
**Color**: One side of the specimens is dark brown, while the other side exhibits a pearl-white hue.
**Location**: Found near a lake shore in Texas.
**Surrounding Geology**: The geological context is not yet determined.
I have taken multiple photographs from various angles, and have also captured images with a scale for size reference.

Does anyone have an idea what these could be? Are these likely to be fossils, and if so, what era or source could they be originating from?
[image: Front side of "leaves"]
[image]

Comment: i might be very wrong on this but it looks like Otoliths,if i am right this is a biology question.

Comment: Yes, probably otoliths. I do not see a leaf like morphology. Usually one would find the leafs' negatives. Which lake?